# Check numbers divisible by 2 and print them in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, list, for-loop, kotlin, integer

I am working on a task as part of my Kotlin course and I've been really stuck on this. I feel like it's something simple but I can't see it. Here is the explanation of what to do for this task:

*You are given a List of integers. Iterate through the given List and print in a single line the elements that are divisible by 2.*

*Sample Input:*

```
8 11 13 2
```

Sample Output:

```
8 2
```

This is my code (I have printed the numbers list to see what numbers I was being provided with, as I am not choosing them, they are given by the course automatically without me seeing them):

```
fun solution(numbers: List<Int>) {
    var divisible = intArrayOf()
    for (i in 0..numbers.lastIndex) {
        if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0){
            divisible = intArrayOf(numbers[i])
        }
    }
    println("$numbers")
    println("${divisible.joinToString("")}")
```

This was my output:

```
[8, 11, 13, 2]
2
```

I think I have done the part of checking if the numbers are divisible by 2 correctly, but I don't fully understand why it only prints 2, and why not 8 first if it divisible by 2. At first I was using a list instead of an array for the divisible variable, so I thought that might have been it, as lists are immutable if I'm not wrong, but it looks like that wasn't it. If anyone could explain to me what I'm doing wrong, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rewrite result holder (`divisible = intArrayOf()`) on each item that is divisible by 2, that's why only last match is stored in `divisible` array.

Instead of

```
divisible = intArrayOf(numbers[i])
```

you should write

```
divisible.add(numbers[i]) // no need to re-initialize
```

**UPDATE**: I've missed that array has no `add` operation. If it's suitable you can use list instead of array in order to have `add` operation available:

```
var divisible = mutableListOf<Int>()
```

P.S. There is a shorter way to do that with Kotlin:

```kotlin
fun solution(numbers: List<Int>) {
    val divisible = numbers.filter { it % 2 == 0 }
    println("$numbers")
    println("${divisible.joinToString(" ")}")
}
```

Comment: Thank you! However, it is telling me "unresolved reference" for add. I'm not sure why, I am googling around to see if I can find something. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Thank you!! That worked flawlessly. I completely forgot about the filter keyword, looks like I'm going to have to restudy the theory! :')

Answer (score 4):

You can use filter with predicate

Example :

```
val list = listOf(8,2,11,15)
```

the solution is so simple with kotlin

```
val result = list.filter { it % 2 == 0 }
```